# Parameter name conflict with class member

Tags: class, delphi, parameters, delphi-xe6

I have a parameter that its name is the same as a procedure within with/do scope. I  realised it after hours of investigating, but now I'm looking for a solution better than just renaming my parameter.

```pascal
Procedure Test(Param:TMyTape);
begin
    with TSomeClass.Create do
    try
        AClassFunc(Param);   // << There is a Param method inside TSomeClass
    finally
        free;
    end;
end;
```

There is `Param` method inside `TSomeClass` that makes the `Param` parameter useless. If the result type of that `Param` method is the same as `Param` parameter, then compiler don't even notice.

**Q**: Is it possible to refer to `Param` parameter to resolve this issue and don't needs to rename the `Param`

Another solution maybe declaring a variable for TSomeClass and don't using with/do clause. I' not looking for this too.

Comment: From my knowledge I say: you have outlined the 2 solutions already. I don't think there is a syntax to allow what you actually want. I suggest you ditch the `with` and assign the object to a variable.

Comment: Ime, `with` only ever creates avoidable problems.

Comment: My **strong recomendation** is to go and rename your `Param` parameteres. In fact avoiud using same names for farameters and methods. Why? Delphi is actually the only Object Pascal compiler that alows this. If you port your code into FPC for instance you Will be greeted with a whole bunch of Duplicate name errors. Besides if you folow Delphi code formatting gudelines all function arguments should have `A` prefix in their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to refer to Param parameter to resolve this issue and don't needs to rename the Param?

Not if you are going to use `with`.

> Another solution maybe declaring a variable for TSomeClass and don't using with/do clause.

This approach will work and is how I would write the code. There are only a very narrow set of scenarios where `with` is appropriate. This is not one of them.